# Floating div expands to 100% in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following simple layout:

```
div.main
{
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #98999E;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.main > div
{
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #FF3700; 
    margin: 2px;
}
div.inner > div
{
     float: right;
}

<div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <div>123</div>
        <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div>999</div>
</div>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, this is rendered as expected - all the content is within the same line:
[image]

However, when testing this in IE7 (or actually IE8 in compatibility mode, to be exact), the first div under the main one takes a width of 100%, and therefore the second is pushed beneath it:
[image]

An example can be found [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EtEXn/).

How can that be fixed?

(**Edit:** 
It turns out that this is happening in IE9 in compatibility mode as well)

(**Edit 2:** It seems that this is happening with `float:right` only, and doesn't with `float:left`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` to the inner div.

[w3.org - 9.2.2 Inline-level elements and inline boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: Even when applied to `.main .inner div`? You should try to at least narrow down which specific element is causing your problem. Try using IE's developer tools to see which element is your problem element... see if `.inner` or `.inner div` is at 100% width.

Comment: Yeah, tried applying to both. The div with the class `innner` is the one taking the 100% width (I also added images for clarification now).

Comment: @Amit: `display: inline` on the inner `div`s works just fine in IE7 and other browsers. See: http://jsfiddle.net/SaAsd/

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

IE might need a width...technically you're supposed to have a width assigned when you are floating an element.

Comment: That would help avoiding the problem, but the problem is that the content may change (can include texts in different languages, which will be in different lengths), so doing so will cause a margin between the content parts in some cases.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the span elements? Sometimes that helps things get back inline for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a div with a style of clear:

```
div.main{
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #98999E;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.main > div {
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #FF3700; 
    margin: 2px;
}
div.inner > div {
    float: right;
}
div.clear{
    clear:both;
}

<div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <div>123</div>
        <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div>999</div>
    <div class='clear'>
</div>
```

This MUST be done with a div (or some other block level element). It's always good CSS form to clear your floats at the same level at the same level as you create them, after all the floated elements. Let me know if it works for you. Cheers.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you specify width for floated `<div>`. That way, you will be more sure about the layout; rather than relying the rendering completely on the browser. Also, it'd hopefully help you visualize what layout you're trying to get at.

Just from the example above, maybe using floating `<span>` inside a `<p>` will accomplish what you need? Or, just right-align a paragraph.

Comment: Fixed widths will be my resort if I won't find any other solution (I'm trying to avoid that because the content width may change). `<span>` elements won't fit because the actual layout is more complicated than the example.